How do I end an automated process in Oracle's Apex that is not stopping?
I made a mistake when creating an automation in Apex and now it will not stop running. Is their a way to stop the automation from running?
I tried running the below code but I get an error that says "ORA-06550: line 2, column 21: PLS-00302: component 'ABORT' must be declared"
begin
    apex_automation.abort(
p_application_id => 502,
p_static_id => 'apex-extract' );
end;



What is your version of APEX ? Is this on premise, ADB ? If this is is a local database, then you could kill the session or ask the DBA to kill the session.

The version is 21.2.0 and I think it is ADB.  The original automation was to insert into a table using views from an external database but apparently I wrote the query poorly and now it will not run in a timely matter. It did work at one point until I tried making an update.

The ABORT method has been introduced in a later version, it's not available in 21.2 docs. You could probably use DISABLE so it doesn't execute the next time after it has finished.
